# Convert video to I420 using ffmpeg.exe

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

What's the command to convert .yuv video to I420 format using ffmpeg? I mean, convert the video using cli, not code to convert. Only one conversion needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert raw YUV to i420 in yuv4mpeg2 (change .y4m into .yuv if you want raw YUV output also):

```
ffmpeg -video_size $WIDTHx$HEIGHT -pixel_format $PIXFMT -i $INPUT.yuv -vf format=yuv420p $OUTPUT.y4m
```

Where you have to fill in all variables. Valid values for PIXFMT could e.g. be yuyv422. See:

```
ffmpeg -pix_fmts
```

for a full list of supported formats.